# Marketing rights on contractor name

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law, advertisements

Let's say I have a consultancy software agreement with a company A. This company A now decides to add my name on some campaign to raise money. Do I have the right to ask them to remove my name from the marketing purpose? In the contract there no clauses regarding any right of using my name for marketing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

That will depend non exactly what company A said about you. If it said 'We work with various skilled partners, including bbb" that would be true, and quite probably they have the right to say that. On the other hand, if it said:

> A and bbb jointly urge you to contribute to the Great cause G. We both think that G is very important to our community, and urge you to support it.

That would be committing your name and reputation without your consent, and you should have the right to insist that they refrain for doing that, and retract the already published statement. That is provided that there was no agreement which arguably allows them to use your name in such a way.

However, even if you do have the legal right to demand a retraction, think carefully. That might be very embarrassing for A, and might harm your business relationship significantly, even if it was basically their fault. Be careful here.